# List<IMultipartFormSection>を設定したUnityWebRequest.uploadHandlerのメモリリーク

Tags: ios, xcode, unity2d

Listを設定したUnityWebRequest.uploadHandlerのメモリリーク

Unityで開発を行っております。
環境はUnity 2018.4.22f1になります。
ファイルをアップロードするために以下のコードを作成しました。

```
// ファイル読み込み
byte[] l_file_data = File.ReadAllBytes( _path );
string l_fileName = "hoge.mp4";

var request = new UnityWebRequest( l_url, "POST");
setRequest( request );
// タイムアウト設定
request.timeout = 300;

List<IMultipartFormSection> requestData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
requestData.Add( new MultipartFormFileSection( "file", l_file_data, l_fileName, "video/*" ) );

if( 0 < user_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "user_id",               user_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < player_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "player_id",             player_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < group_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "group_id",              group_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < team_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "team_id",               team_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < game_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "game_id",               game_id.ToString() ) );

if( !title.Equals( "" ) )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "title",                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( title ) ) );
if( !comment.Equals( "" ) )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "comment",               System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( comment ) ) );

byte[] boundary = UnityWebRequest.GenerateBoundary();
byte[] formSections = UnityWebRequest.SerializeFormSections( requestData, boundary );

// データ設定
request.uploadHandler   = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw( formSections );
request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
 
// ヘッダを設定
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" );
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(boundary) );
request.SetRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Bearer "+ _access_token );
// アプリ名、Ver、プラットフォーム
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Escore-Env", "app="+APP_NAME+"; ver="+VER+"; os="+isOS() );

yield return request.Send();
```

このコードで120MBほどのファイルをアップロードする際にWindowsエディター上ではメモリの異常増加は見られなかったのですが、
iPad上で確認した際にメモリが800MB以上増えメモリリークが発生しました。

ファイル自体は120MBですが、なぜここまで使用メモリーが増えるのでしょうか。
こちら改善方法をご存じでしょうか。
UnityのVerアップも考えておりますが、そちらで解決できるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

メモリを浪費していると思われる箇所が、いくつかあります。

```cs
byte[] formSections = UnityWebRequest.SerializeFormSections( requestData, boundary );
```

この処理は、マルチパートのデータをまとめて一つのメッセージボディのためのデータにする処理です。
まとめるわけですから、出来上がるデータ(`formSections`)のサイズは、元のデータの合計よりも多くなると思われますので、この時点で120M以上のバイト配列が2つ存在することになります。

更に、`UnityEngine.Networking.UploadHandlerRaw`ですが、[マニュアル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandlerRaw.html)には以下のように書かれています。

> このサブクラスは**コンストラクション時にネイティブコードのメモリバッファーに入力データをコピーし**、 HTTP リクエストボディデータとしてデータそのままを送信します。

この言葉を素直に受け取れば、`UploadHandlerRaw`のコンストラクタでも同サイズのバッファが使われている可能性があります。

対策としては、[`UploadHandlerFile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/ScriptReference/Networking.UploadHandlerFile.html)を使うことを検討してください。
マニュアルにも、「You can use it to send a large amount of data to the server with a low memory footprint.」と書かれています。
ただし、一度に遅れるのは一つのファイルのみで、他のデータを一緒に送ることはできなさそうです。

もしそれがダメであれば、`UnityWebRequest.SerializeFormSections`を使わないとか、そもそも`UnityWebRequest`を使わないとか、考えなければなりません。

Comment: 「UploadHandlerRaw」クラスではなく「UploadHandlerFile」クラスを使用してアップロードを行いましたがこちらも送信時にデータコンバートを行いメモリ容量を多く使用しているので、190MBほどのファイルをアップロードした際にメモリリークを起こしてハングいたしました。
他方法はご存じでしょうか

Comment: 回答にも書いてありますが、それでダメならUnityWebRequestを使わないで、自力でソケットを使ってHTTP通信して、一度にファイルの内容を読み込まないようにやり取りする方法などありますが、ただそんなに簡単ではありませんので、HTTP通信をする他のライブラリを探してみてもいいでしょう。それがダメなら、あまりやりたくはないけれども、何回かに分けて送信するしかないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: Unityで分割してファイルを送信するライブラリやアセットなどご存じでしょうか。

Comment: そのようなものは知りませんし、おそらくないと思います。